# Google Forms & Sheets: Drop down answer from Sheet tabs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Form and linked it to an existing Google Sheet with multiple tabs on it, I now need to:

- Get Sheet tab names and populate a Form drop down question with them

I've found App Script code to get Sheet tab names from inside the sheet itself but not from the Form. I'm new to App script and how everything connects. If the best solution is to create a Form solely with App Script then that is what I will strive to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this add-on called **formRanger**.

Simply follow the given [Script instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YvgrxeZJNb2CBpSra1j59Mh1bVpk4vBQYLOoyVjby7A/edit?hl=en&forcehl=1) and also install the script in your responses spreadsheet.

Additionally, this [discussion in Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/fLNCa09zzV4) might also help. Hope it works for you!